# Dynamic generation of textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In my webpage i have one textbox(hotel name) and a button.

Suppose if i add value "sun shine" in textbox(hotel name) and click on button , the dynamically generated textbox should also have value "sun shine" in it. I am able to generate dynamic textbox using javascript so far. But the value it takes it just the first word i.e "sun" for eg.

javascript code:

```
val=document.getElementById("hotel_name").value;
....
newdiv.innerHTML = '<input type=text size=15 id=' + hotel[num] + ' value=' + val + '>;
```

Any idea on how to go about it.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surround attributes with quotes:

```
'<input type="text" size="15" id="' + hotel[num] + '" value="' + val + '">';
//           ^    ^      ^  ^    ^                  ^       ^           ^
```

Otherwise the generated HTML will look like:

```
<input type=text size=15 id=something value=sun shine>
```

Only `sun` will be treated as being part of `value`. `shine` will be considered as an (invalid) attribute (as you can already see on how syntax highlighting is applied to this code snippet).

That's the reason why you should always use quotes for attribute values.

Comment: @user735399 - What @Felix demonstrates is what's wrong with your code; your usage is flawed. I suggest DOM methods instead of adding with `innerHTML`. (You can see my still coffee-deprived answer for an example.)

Answer (score 1):

As Felix points out, your plain html is being interpreted, which is causing you to inadvertently have issues with how values are interpreted when inserted. Instead of using `innerHTML`, just use DOM methods to add your input. They work better, are faster, and don't have this particular problem.

```
<textarea id="hotel_name">sun shine</textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="doStuff()" value="Do Stuff"/>

function doStuff(){
    hotel = {'num':25};
    hotel_name=document.getElementById("hotel_name").value;
    val = hotel_name;
    newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
    newinput = document.createElement('input');
    newinput.type = "text";
    newinput.size = 15;
    newinput.id = hotel['num'];
    newinput.value = val;
    newdiv.appendChild(newinput);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8PF2A/1/

Comment: +1 creating DOM elements is better in general. However for simple elements, using `innerHTML` is often sufficient (*if* you do it right).

Comment: @Felix - I don't disagree with the last part; just that it's often a little more code, but a better overall practice to use DOM methods. You never know, the OP could be inserting a textarea using DOM methods (what it sounds like), then using innerHTML to insert a child node. And could be doing it 50 times...